# Loop ARIMA combination to minimize RMSE

Tags: r, loops, forecasting, arima, forecast

**Goal**  : I want to create a loop in R that takes every combination of an ARIMA model on my insample data to get the smallest RMSE when I compare it with the out-of-sample data.

**What I have**

This is what I have when I do it manually:

```
#Creating the insample and outsample data 
insamp <- ts(y[1:48], frequency = 12)
outsamp <- y[49:60]

#Createing the ARIMA model 
fit <- Arima(insamp, order = c(1,0,0), include.drift = TRUE)

#forecasting the length of the out of sample data
fcast2 <- forecast(fit, h=length(outsamp))

#concluding from the RMSE how my model is performing with the out-of-sample data
accuracy(fcast, outsamp)
                ME      RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.2536812  9.158607  6.86326 0.05216278 2.932405 0.3324541 0.01516999
Test set     8.4465515 26.409409 20.54116 1.20298077 4.552727 0.9950071         NA
```

**What i need**

I need a loop that takes every combination of Arima(i,j,k) and compares it to RMSE which the **accuracy** function outputs.  It should provide the outputs of the  (i, j, k) that minimize the RMSE.

Comment: You can use `auto.arima` from `forecast` package for automatic selection of p, d, q with lowest error.

Comment: Description: "Returns best ARIMA model according to either AIC, AICc or BIC value. The function conducts a search over possible model within the order constraints provided." 

i'm not looking for AIC or BIC. i'm looking for the best forcast for my out of sample data

Comment: `auto.arima` does that only. Have you tried `auto.arima` function from `forecast` package?

Comment: What kind of error message do you get when testing the models in a loop? What is not working?